# php/mysql search query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, search, syntax

I have a problem with my search query, $s_query.
The user can search a type (Date, Title, or Location) which corresponds to a colum in my mysql database

```
$search_type =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
$search_query =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_query']);

if ($search_query == "") {
  echo "<p>Please enter a search...</p>";
  exit;}

$s_query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `$search_type` == `$search_query` ";

$s_result1=mysql_query($s_query);

if (!$s_result1) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    //header ("Location: /UC_page.html");
}

$s_row = mysql_fetch_array($s_result1);
$s_num1=mysql_numrows($s_result1);
mysql_close();
```

mysql_error says: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== `1956`'

i have tried every operator possible and every kind of syntax i could find, but im stuck.
at one point i got the date to work, but not any of the strings.
thanks in advance.

Comment: No need for `==` just one `=` should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you have two problems. First, you're surrounding your value with `, which is invalid. Use `"` or `'` instead.

Also, `==` is not valid syntax, you need to use a single `=` instead. Although, looking at what you're doing, you probably want to use `LIKE` instead, for a case-insensitive search.

So this query should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `$search_type` = '$search_query'
```

Or with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `$search_type` LIKE '$search_query'
```

Answer (score 3):

You are putting ` (on top of the tab button) around your insert value. Those only go on the field. YOu shoudl use ' (on top of the slash button) for the value.

Comment: thank you for your response i tried it and got mysql_error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 'Lorem Ipsum''

Answer (score 0):

This might help you understand what query MySQL is expecting:

```
$s_query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `" . $search_type . "` = " . $search_query;
```

Also make sure you add the necessary quotes to `$search_query`. EG: If it is a string then surround it with `'`.